# Scripts won't load in browser angular2

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, node.js, mean

For some reason, I cannot get to set up my index page without having loads of trouble.

Here's my browser:

[image: My Browser]

And here's my index:

[image: My Index]

I've got really no clue this time.

He doesn't want to load a local script, yes it points towards it :)

Comment: If you are sure the file is present locally, remove ../ from the start of script src and it should work.

Comment: @ArunGeorge didn't work.

Comment: can you open the requested URL in browser? if not... either this is an issue with file permissions or the path_to_file is incorrect.

Comment: I run trough webstorm on localhost

Answer (score 0):

As per your project structure your src path is wrong you have to set it as a **src="../../node_modules/Your remaining path"** so you have to go 2 level in up direction for get your file.

Comment: My index file is located in the src file. the src file is on same level as the node_module file, so I'm going 1 back which gets me in my project folder, where my node_modules is situated.